# Accessing member by index via property

Tags: c#, list, properties

How can I access an element by index of a member List via a property? For example:

```
public class foo{
    private List<type> list = new List<type>;
    public List{
        get{/*basically, what goes here?*/}
    }
}
//Much later....
foo Foo = new foo();
Console.WriteLine(Foo.List[1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to consider is what ability you want to provide to *update* the list.  If you just expose the *list* as a get-only property, then there's nothing stopping someone from modifying the list:

```
public class foo{
    private List<type> list = new List<type>;
    public List<type> List{
        get{return list}
    }
}
//Much later....
foo Foo = new foo();
Foo.List.Clear();   // perfectly legal
```

If, however, you want a "read-only" list exposed, then you can expose the list as read-only:

```
public class foo{
    private List<type> list = new List<type>;
    public IList<type> List{
        get{return list.AsReadOnly()}
    }
}
//Much later....
foo Foo = new foo();
Foo.List.Clear();   // not possible
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment to another question, it is unclear whether you want to expose the *list* as a property or access *items* by index.  For the latter you can add an indexer to the class:

```
public class foo{
    private List<type> list = new List<type>;
    public type this[int i]{
        get{return list[i]}
        get{list[i] = value}
    }
}
//Much later....
foo Foo = new foo();
Console.WriteLine(Foo[1]);
```

Comment: I want to use an index, but not apply it to the whole class (there are a few lists in my real-world code, so each one needs a property which allows Foo.List[i], Foo.OtherList[i] etc)

Comment: Then just expose the list itself as a property (with the option to make it read-only as I mention)

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a list, you can just return that list in the property

```
public class foo{
    private List<type> list = new List<type>;
    public List<type> List{
        get{ return list; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the one you want.

Comment: I don't want to return the whole list, just the element.

Comment: @Joe - your example exposes the _list_ as a property, then gets one _element_ from that list - do you want to add an indexed to `foo` instead?

Comment: @DStanley, how do I set it up so that it gets one element from a list, then exposes that element as a property, then? I don't want to add an index.

Comment: you mean like `get{ return list[0]; }`?

Comment: so... you want to return a single element from the list? or you want an indexer property?

Comment: @DarrenKopp Return a single element, as commented on another answer an indexer property is no good as there is more than one List in the class.

Comment: so then use the first syntax. you would use the index accessor on the list returned from the property. there is no other alternative.

Comment: There's no way to add an indexer to just the property? Damn. ReadOnly it is, then.

Comment: yeah, indexer applies to the type. readonly is your best bet.